# Using Railslist, on rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I'm trying to modify railslist to work with Rails 3. I keep getting this error when trying to view `/classifieds`

> TypeError (can't convert nil into
>   Array)
>   app/controller/classifieds_controller.rb:in
>   'index'

```
def index
    @classifieds = Classified.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"  
    render :layout => 'main'
end
```

Comment: What version of will_paginate are you using? (`gem list will_paginate`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a pre-release version of will_paginate if you're using Rails 3. Put the following in your Gemfile in place of what you had for will_paginate before:

```
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2"
```